# How to provide jmeter thread group , Ramp up peridod and Loop count?

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to jmeter I have the following scenario. I want the jmeter to hit the given url, I have 13 such url in a csv file.

I want to hit the url at the rate of 2 requests per second for a given time period of 60 seconds.

In this case how should I specify my thread group, Ramp-up period and  Loop count.

I understood the basic like 10 thread with 10 second rampup with a loop count of 1 will run 1 request per second for 10 user. But I'm not sure how to specify when we have 13 such urls.

Atleast any link for the given scenario is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I understood the basic like 10 thread with 10 second rampup with a loop count of 1 will run 1 request per second for 10 user

not necessarily, JMeter waits for response from the previous [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) prior to executing the next one, the configuration means that JMeter will start 1 user each second, it doesn't guarantee 1 request per second.

The easiest way of achieving X requests per second throughput is using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/)

[image]

Make sure to supply the **sufficient** number of Threads, i.e. if your application response time is 1000ms - 2 threads should be enough, if it's 2000 ms - you will need at least 2 threads, etc.

There is a special thread group: [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) which can be connected to the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so it will automatically kick off extra virtual users if the current amount will not be enough in order to conduct the required load.